# Upload image to Odoo12 using XML-RPC

Tags: php, python, odoo, xml-rpc

I am using xml-rpc to create new employee in Odoo, what I did so far is sending employee name and now I am trying to send and upload employee image to Odoo as well using xml-rpc. I have a php page that connected with Odoo.

```
  <?php>
     ........
     ........
     ........
     ........

     $id = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password,
      'hr.employee','create', array(array('name'=>$_POST['name'], 'image'=>$_POST['image'])));

  ?>
```

I do not know how to do it .I added this line 'image'=>$_POST['image'] but it does not work.

Comment: What's the specific problem you're having?

Comment: @Calum Halpin I do not know how to do it .I added this line 'image'=>$_POST['image'] but it does not work.

Comment: odoo store images as string base64, so you need to encode your image to base6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write as following :

```
<?php>
     ........
     ........
     ........
     ........

     $b64image = base64_encode(file_get_contents('your image path'));
     $id = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password,
      'hr.employee','create', array(array('name'=>$_POST['name'], 'image'=>$b64image)));

  ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

`odoo` store images as string base64, so you need to encode your image to base64 then send the string in `create` call or `write` call

Comment: I don't know how to do it in PHP just search how to convert a binary object to string base64 you will find a lot of example in the web